# Why is the output operator 'os << value' and not 'value >> os'?

Tags: c++

I am learning about streaming. The standard streams provide the `<<` operator which can be declared as:

```
ostream& operator<<(stream& os, CLASS& rc);
```

Why is it impossible to declare it as this?

```
ostream& operator>>(CLASS& rc, stream& os);
```

Then I may be able to do something like:

```
rc.something >> os;
```

as part of its implementation.

---

**Edit** as people have helped me learn more about this, I am thankful.

However I am stuck at how to implement actually it.

I have tried

```
ostream& operator >> (const SomeClass& refToCls, stream& os)
{
   refToCls.iVar >> os;
   return os;
}
```

but it fails. How can I fix it?

Comment: Note, you should use `CLASS const& rc`.

Comment: You also mean istream when using >> don't you?

Comment: @Martin, thank you for joining, please look at the Answer and offer me an implementation of >> that makes such chaining work, if possible.

Comment: @Martin: Read the question again :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In fact it's possible to define

```
ostream& operator>>(CLASS& rc, ostream& os);
```

But then you must chain it like this:

```
a >> (b >> (c >> str));
```

The `>>` operator is left-associative, so by default this:

```
a >> b >> c >> str;
```

is equivalent to:

```
((a >> b) >> c) >> str;
```

which has a wrong meaning.

Comment: +1: Indeed. It most certainly _can_ be done; it's just pretty stupid.

Comment: @Dalton: because it's unintuitive. doing so is asking for bugs `1 >> 1 >> cout;` would print `0`.

Comment: @Tomalak, I mean why you say it is pretty stupid to implement >>

Comment: @Dalton: Have you at all noticed how the streams work: `cout << "Enter your name"; cin >> yourName;`? `<<` is insertion and `>>` is extraction. That's the convention that works well.

Comment: @ybungalobill, your post is really helpful, thanks a lot. (after I read your edit.)

Comment: @Dalton: Because `<<` is conventional for output, because that's how the standard library does it, because it's a pain in the ass working around the handicaps ybungalobill mentioned, because nobody else in the world does things this way, and because you already have a perfectly good output syntax convention that's completely the _opposite_ of what you're suggesting.

Comment: @Tomalak, thank you for your reply, I edit my OP for better request.

Comment: @Dalton: Regarding your edit, you wrote `stream` instead of `ostream`. And of course you need to write `os << refToCls.iVar` inside. Perfect example of why this is silly, confusing syntax to use. And please do not add chunks on to previous questions: file new ones.

Comment: Yes, that is perfectly silly I can't catch up with,My problem is how to write it which is totally on topic? if you know you can post one. You keep pointing out mistakes but not try to provide an ultimate solution

Comment: @Dalton: Huh? The "ultimate solution" is to use `<<` like everybody else. I believe I opened with that one.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can do it without worrying about associativity, with a helper class to collect the inputs and then send it to ostream:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>

class ReversePrinter
{
    std::string acc;
public:
    template <class T>
    ReversePrinter(const T& value)
    {
        *this >> value;
    }

    template <class T>
    ReversePrinter& operator>>(const T& value)
    {
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << value;
        acc += ss.str();
        return *this;
    }
    std::ostream& operator>>(std::ostream& os)
    {
        std::reverse(acc.begin(), acc.end());
        return os << acc;
    }
};

struct R
{
    template <class T>
    ReversePrinter operator>>(const T& value) {
        return ReversePrinter(value);
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::string name = "Ben";
    int age = 14;
    const char* hobby = "reading backwards";
    R() >> "Hello, my name is " >> name >> "\nI'm " 
        >> age >> " years old and I like " >> hobby >> std::cout;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't you want to do `acc = ss.str() + acc;` and then skip the `std::reverse`? Otherwise, wouldn't it print out all the words backwards?