# Defining >> operator

Tags: c++

I can not implement >> operator

```
ostream&operator>>(Mode&refMode,ostream&os)
```

to perform chaining operations as

```
refMode.iMode>>(refMode.jMode>>os)
```

Would you please provide me an implementation of it ?

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do here.  Normally we use `<<` to stream into an output.

Comment: @Oli: FYI, it's related to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7052568/streaming-operator-doubt).

Comment: Ah, ok.  @Dalton: What have you tried so far?  (Disregarding that this is somewhat pointless...)

Comment: -1 for no context and no attempt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Oli said in his comment, we ***normally*** define `operator <<` for streaming. You shouldn't change the usual semantics of the operator just to be fancy. That said, I don't see any other technical impediments for your idea. Example:

```
#include <iostream>
class A
{
   int i;
public:
   A(int i = 0):i(i){}
};

std::ostream& operator>>(const A& a, std::ostream& os)
{
    return os << a.i;
}

int main()
{
   A a(4), b(3);
   a >> (b >> std::cout);
}
```

But why would you want to do such a thing?

Comment: Thank you Armen, I ask so because I don't know if that is possible or not.

Comment: Surely you can do better than that. This one sends things left-to-right, as would seem more intuitive: http://ideone.com/PwtP1

Answer (score 2):

I am sorry, but both operator >> and << are left associative operators. You simply can NOT do something like `obj1 >> obj2 >> obj3 >> stream` and expect it to work properly. At the best case you need huge amounts of parentheses: `obj1 >> (obj2 >> (obj3 >> stream))`.

Just go with the conventional syntax:

```
std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& stream, const MyObject& obj)
{
    stream << obj.variable1 << obj.variable2 << etc etc;
    return stream;
}
```

This way `stream << obj1 << obj2 << obj3` is possible.

Comment: To be fair to the OP, he's already acknowledged the need to do force the associativity with parentheses.

Comment: Yup but he might forget about it one day and wonder why doesn't it work. Principle of least astonishment and such.

Answer (score 1):

[Elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7052568/streaming-operator-doubt), you gave us your attempt:

```
ostream&operator >> (const SomeClass& refToCls, stream&os)
{
   refToCls.iVar>>os;
   return os;
}
```

And I told you that you still need the conventional syntax *inside*, because you haven't made a version of your backwards syntax for whatever `refToCls.iVar` is. You also meant `ostream`, not `stream`:

```
ostream&operator >> (const SomeClass& refToCls, ostream& os)
{
   os << refToCls.iVar;
   return os;
}

SomeClass x;
x >> cout;
```

And.. a final word of warning that **this is a really bad idea**.

Comment: Thank you Tomalak, you are fast with your replies.